# Create a std::thread object in thread A, join in thread B

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

Is it allowed to call `join()` on a `std::thread` object that was created in a different thread, given that the object is properly synchronized between threads?

For example:

```
void cleanup(std::thread t)
{
    t.join();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t{[] { /* something */ }};

    std::thread c{cleanup, std::move(t)};
    c.join();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `join()` can be called on a valid thread object by any thread except by the thread itself.

> **Error Conditions**
>
> resource_deadlock_would_occur if `this->get_id() == std::this_thread::get_id()`.
>
> no_such_process if the thread is not valid
>
> invalid_argument if `joinable()` is false